# Luns not taken by the windows server admin

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage, storage-area-network

I have a scenario based question...Something , I haven't faced till now ,but i would be interested  to know the answer.

If i have assigned a luns (say, of 50 GB) and put them in storage group.However, the windows server team did not grab that lun but sent an acknowledgment saying the Luns are alingned.

I would like to know what will happen to the Luns that belong to the SG ..in my opinion they will remain in the SG as unassigned Luns ..or is there a possibility that the lUns will move back to the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which storage you configure, I assume from your previous questions this is EMC Cx700. As this array cannot have virtual provisioning (thin provisioning), nothing will happen to LUNs they will just sit there waiting until you delete them.

If you use storage with thin provisioning, LUNs will still be there, but they will not have space reserved. So this means you can temporarily use "their" space for other purposes.